# Sequence $b_{n+1}=\frac{3-b_n^2}{2}$ - problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Can anyone please help me with this because I honestly don't know how to start.
 
Prove that sequence $b_n$ has limit and find it.
Show that sequence $b_n$ is not monotonic and show that $b_n$ is the Cauchy sequence.
$$b_1=0$$
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{3-b_n^2}{2}$$

Comment: The sequence is recursive

Comment: Do you know what monotonic is? Have you computed a few values of $b_n$, say $n$ from $1$ to $4$?

Answer (score 0):

We can say that $\frac{3}{2}\geq b_n\geq0\,\forall n>0$ since by induction we can show that,

$$0<\frac{3-\frac{3}{2}^2}{2}\leq b_{n+1}=\frac{3-b_n^2}{2}\leq \frac{3-0^2}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Hence

$$|b_{n+1}-1|=\frac{1}{2}|b_{n}^2-1|=\frac{1}{2}|b_n-1||b_n+1|<\frac{1}{2}|b_n-1|$$

I think you can now go ahead and complete the rest. The limit is of course = $1$

Comment: By bounding $b_n \le \frac32$, you get $$|b_{n+1}-1| \le \frac54|b_n-1|$$
but $\frac54$ is greater than $1$...